# First fragment to be added to the main activity when application starts up

Tags: android, android-fragments, slidingdrawer

Suppose I am creating an `Android` application which has a `Navigation drawer` and set of `fragment`s. When user clicks on an option in the `Navigation drawer` the corresponding `fragment` is loaded. The application has only one `activity` (`Main activity`) and it has no `view`.

When the application is first started which `fragment` gets loaded into the `main activity`? How does the `application` know which `fragment` to be loaded first without user interaction? How to set a custom `fragment` to be loaded automatically when the application starts?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just perform the same FragmentTransaction you use to replace the fragment on user interaction and in the `onCreate()` method of your Activity. But you have to check if savedInstanceState is null like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.flFragmentContainer, MainFragment.newInstance());
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```